# Destructuring macro for ST-JSON JSO object

Tags: json, macros, lisp, common-lisp, ccl

I have another question regarding decoding JSON in Common Lisp. I settled on `ST-JSON` as my tool. I am able to get a `JSO` object containing the JSON data, and access all fields with `st-json:getjso`. I wanted to write a macro similar in principle to `destructuring-bind` that would provide local bindings to variables named after JSON fields (since then I started doubting if this is a good idea, but that's a different question). I came up with the following:

```
(defmacro destructure-jso (jso &body body)
  (let (keys values)
    (st-json:mapjso #'(lambda (key value)
            (push key keys)
            (push value values))
            jso)
    `(destructuring-bind ,keys ,values
       ,@body)))
```

But when I try to use it on a `JSO` object, I get the error `The value PARAMS is not of the expected type STRUCTURE.` where `PARAMS` is the object. Can someone explain this to me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently, you are using `destructure-jso` like this:

```
(let ((params (st-json:read-json-from-string "{\"foo\":42,\"bar\":\"baz\"}")))
  (destructure-jso params
    (list foo bar)))
```

However, `destructure-jso`, being a macro, gets handled at macro expansion time, much before the JSON even gets parsed. `params` is passed to your macro as a symbol, without being evaluated; and even if its evaluation was attempted, it would be unbound.

So, if you want to write a `destructure-jso`, you will need the list of keys at macro expansion time. You could pass the list in a normal way:

```
> (defmacro destructure-jso-2 (vars json &body body)
    `(let ,(mapcar #'(lambda (var)
                       (list var `(getjso ,(string-downcase (symbol-name var)) ,json)))
                   vars)
       ,@body))
DESTRUCTURE-JSO-2

> (let ((params (st-json:read-json-from-string "{\"foo\":42,\"bar\":\"baz\"}")))
    (destructure-jso-2 (foo bar)
    params
  (list foo bar)))
(42 "baz")
```

Or, if you like, use a "template" JSON for creating the mappings:

```
> (defmacro destructure-jso-3 (template json &body body)
    (let (bindings)
      (st-json:mapjso #'(lambda (key val)
                          (declare (ignore val))
                          (push (list (intern (string-upcase key)) `(getjso ,key ,json))
                                bindings))
                      (st-json:read-json-from-string template))
      `(let ,bindings
         ,@body)))
DESTRUCTURE-JSO-3

> (let ((params (st-json:read-json-from-string "{\"foo\":42,\"bar\":\"baz\"}")))
    (destructure-jso-3 "{\"foo\":null,\"bar\":null}"
        params
      (list foo bar)))
(42 "baz")
```

Here, the variable bindings come from the first (template) JSON, values from the second one. The template JSON is parsed at macroexpansion time, the `params` JSON every time your code is executed.

Whether either of these is a useful approach for you or not, I do not know.

Comment: Thanks @jlahd. The first approach (`destructure-jso-2`) is more similar to what I wanted and also makes it easier to avoid problems like shadowing interned symbols.